# ImportError after Successful Installing Packages in Conda Environment

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, conda

I installed python-3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and planned to have python-3.6 as well with conda environment. For the conda enviornment with python-3.6, I named it as py36. However, though I installed package a package in (py36) environment, python complained that there was no such module. Why was python confused?

Below is the code I ran:

```
$conda create --name py36 python=3.6
$ source activate py36
(py36) xxx@Alienware:~/crawler$ conda install --name py36 -c anaconda cached-pro
(py36) xxx@Alienware:~/crawler$ conda list -n py36
# packages in environment at /home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/py36:
#
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0  
cached-property           1.5.1                     <pip>
cached-property           1.5.1                    py36_0    anaconda
certifi                   2018.11.29               py36_0  
libedit                   3.1.20170329         h6b74fdf_2  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
openssl                   1.1.1a               h7b6447c_0  
pip                       18.1                     py36_0  
python                    3.6.7                h0371630_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5
scrapy                    1.5.1                    py36_0   
setuptools                40.6.3                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               h7b6447c_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
wheel                     0.32.3                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  


(py36) xxx@Alienware:~/crawler$ scrapy crawl transcripts --logfile output.log
```

Yet I got the following output. But I just checked that cached_property was installed in my environment. What did I miss here?

```
ImportError: No module named 'cached_property'
```

Comment: When you run *pip*, there's a chance you're still using global default Python, not the virtualenv's one.

Comment: Do you have `scrapy` installed in your `virtualenv`?

Comment: @dmitryro Yes you are right. I added the results from conda list -n py36. It also confirms that the package was successfully installed.

Comment: @Mortz Yes I did. I'm not using virtualenv but conda enviornment which is similar.